# Read input exactly n number in space seperated input value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have input statement like this - "First line contains an integer denoting the test cases 'T'. Every test case contains an integer value depicting size of array 'N' and **N integer elements are to be inserted in the next line with spaces between them.**"

I am writing code like this -

**Code 1 : -**

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
  size = int(input())  # input size of array
  numbers = list(map(int, input().split())
```

**Problem -** array size is not being used, means let us suppose I entered array size is 3 and I am inserting value 1 2 3 4 5. it accepts. Here numbers size is 5 but it should accepts 3 size only.

**Code 2 :-**

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
  size = int(input())  # input size of array
  arr = []
  for j in range(size):
    num = int(input())
    arr.append(num)
```

**Problem -** Here I am able to read exaclty 3 values(i:e size) but when inserting space separated value like 1 2 3, getting ValueError.

**Code in Java :-**

```
 int n = sc.nextInt();
 int[] arr = new int[n];
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){   
    int e = sc.nextInt();               
    arr[i] = e;
 }
```

Here we are giving either space separated value or in new line, It works fine.

**How to deal with this?**

Comment: If you get too many/too few values, what should you do?  Simply check `if size != len(numbers):` and then raise an exception/print an error message if you were given bad input

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I wanted to restrict to insert only given size.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  please suggest in competative programming how should we take input.

Comment: @Yahya what is best way to take input in competitive programming ? thats all i want. please suggest

Comment: Use your code 1, and just check for malformed inputs with an `if` statement.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh . ok. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one -

```
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()][0:size]
```